# Good way for send notification from service to WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service, ipc

I'm developing an application (school project) which is a service + an external WPF UI.
I've planned to use WCF for UI-to-service communication.
Anyway, the service needs to notify the UI if some events occurs, and I'm looking for a simple way to do it.

Of course, any basic IPC would work, but I'd prefer not to mess up with pipes, mutex, events and so on.

In a native win32 app I'd have used a `WM_USER` message, but as far as I have understood it's not natively supported by WPF.

Can someone point out some possible/best solution?

Thanks

Comment: WCF supports duplex communication.

Comment: Mutex and Events are not really IPC.  They're cross-process synchronization primitives which don't communicate data.  The recommended way of doing what you want is to use named pipes.  WCF will wrap a pipe so you can use WCF to communicate through pipes; or you can use the .NET pipes API.  Another way would be to use sockets--which WCF will also wrap.

Comment: I definitely need to study WCF deeply. Anyway, if I want to do a duplex WCF communication can the service work while the UI is not running (the other WCF end is not reachable?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WCF [Callback Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S2) for notifying the client.

Answer (score 2):

One approach I've used is a shared database table that acts as a queue. Your UI app keeps track of the last record it's seen (either an index or timestamp) and periodically polls for new events. Bind your queries and updates with transactions to prevent concurrency problems. One advantage of a database is that it persists the events which help with debugging and crashes. [System.Data.Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/), and [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) are good choices.

Another alternative is to use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) as a publish/subscribe message system via TCP/IP. ZeroMQ is very easy to setup and can handle high message volumes.

Both the database and ZeroMQ approach let you put the UI app on a remote machine instead of requiring it to be on the service host.

I also recommend that you define your events as a class and serialize it to a string regardless of whether you're using a database or ZeroMQ to pass events. I recommend [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)'s excellent, easy to use JSON serializer.

Comment: Actually I already have a Sql Server CE. The problem is that a 'polling' solution is not what I'm looking for, otherwise I can use WCF to ask periodically the service for things to be notified. I've also used RabbitMQ for a NodeJS/Reverse Ajax project, but it requires additional software running.

Comment: ZeroMQ doesn't require a separate message broker app - you add an assembly to the service and the UI client, with the service also acting as the broker. And it's available on NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Are your service and application running on separate machines? If your service sends a notification while your app is not running, do you want to be notified when your app next runs? If so, your best option is [Message Queuing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx).

Comment: I've never heard about this :) I'll have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You can try `EventAggregator` in order to send notification (Subscribe + Publish methods)

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx